# Knative: Enabling automatic TLS certificate provisioning - not working

Tags: tls1.2, istio, cert-manager, knative, knative-serving

**I am trying to "Enabling automatic TLS certificate provisioning"**

I have a working ClusterIssuer(status: "True") and I am able to manually create a Certificate(status: "True").

I am trying to enable [Automatic TLS provision mode](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/docs/serving/using-auto-tls.md#clusterissuer-for-dns-01-challenge).

Environment setup:

```
Knative: v0.12
Istio: v1.4 (SDS)
cert-manager: v0.13.1

kubectl version                                                               
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.9", GitCommit:"2e808b7cb054ee242b68e62455323aa783991f03", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:33:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.9-gke.9", GitCommit:"a9973cbb2722793e2ea08d20880633ca61d3e669", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-07T22:35:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I have the following gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: knative-ingress-gateway
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      # Sends 301 redirect for all http requests.
      # Omit to allow http and https.
      httpsRedirect: false
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "mydomain.com"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
```

And when applying:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-go
  namespace: default
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go # The URL to the image of the app
        env:
        - name: TARGET
          value: "Go Sample v1"
```

I can(note: httpsRedirect: false):

```
curl http://helloworld-go.default.mydomain.com                                       
Hello Go Sample v1!
```

But when trying with https:

```
curl https://helloworld-go.default.mydomain.com
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to helloworld-go.default.mydomain.com:443
```

**Also:**

The Knative documentation state: "In this mode, a single Certificate will be provisioned per namespace and is reused across the Knative", but I dont see any certificates in any namespaces.

Note that `kubectl get ksvc` url is http and not https:

```
kubectl get ksvc
NAME            URL                                      LATESTCREATED         LATESTREADY           READY   REASON
helloworld-go   http://helloworld-go.default.mydomain.com   helloworld-go-lxr2n   helloworld-go-lxr2n   True
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Comment: Nope, I am still waiting for fix. Please let me know if you come come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. But with version 0.16.0. I fixed it by not using "Enabling automatic TLS certificate provisioning" with cert-manager instead I used the HTTP-01 directly provided from knative.

How to automatically provisioning TLS certificates using Let’s Encrypt HTTP01 challenges:

1. go to https://knative.dev/docs/install/any-kubernetes-cluster/#optional-serving-extensions
2. click on "TLS via HTTP01"
3. Follow the instruction
4. Should work