# Is Google blocking for Knative tls setup?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, cert-manager, knative, knative-serving

I have used a week trying to setup [Knative automatically enabling tls](https://knative.dev/v0.9-docs/serving/using-auto-tls/) on Google Kubernetes Engine.

[It simply does not work!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60429443/knative-enabling-automatic-tls-certificate-provisioning-not-working)

Now I just found [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/auto-tls) and I am reluctant to totally obfuscate everything.

Could this be blocking existing kubernetes(GKE)?

```
gcloud run domain-mappings describe --domain=mydomain.com                                                                                                                       2 ↵
Please choose a target platform:
 [1] Cloud Run (fully managed)
 [2] Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on Google Cloud
 [3] Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on VMware
 [4] cancel
```

And if I choose number two, will it open up for https?

Comment: There's nothing "blocking" here. You're just supposed to specify `--platform=gke`, or otherwise it's asking you which "cloud run" you mean. I recommend you give it a try. `describe` is not a destructive action.

Comment: @AhmetB-Google Does the Cloud Run addon is required for allowing the Cloud Run command API to access to the cluster? Or installing simply Knative is enough ?

Comment: Self-installed Knative is not recognized by gcloud (or Cloud Console). You need to use the addon.